# escape comma in snowflake copy into

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
COPY INTO @TMP_STG
FROM table
FILE_FORMAT = (
                TYPE=CSV
                EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = false
                FIELD_DELIMITER=','
               )
single = false
max_file_size=4900000000;
```

I'm generating a file from a sf table using COPY INTO, set the delimiter as ','. But there's a column which contains comma in the value, e.g.

```
col1     col2            col3
CAD      Toronto,ON      10
USD      Dallas,Texas    10
```

I was thinking to add ESCAPE = '/' inside FILE_FORMAT, but also noticed it mentions to use with FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY, do I need to use them together? How do I make sure Toronto,ON is in col2 and not divided by delimiter?

Comment: if your data is enclosed by a double-quote or something similar, you should be able to just use that without any special escape.  Is your data already quote-qualified?

Comment: It really is going to depend on what the CSV raw data looks like.  Does it actually enclose the fields? Does the data actually escape the [COMMA]'s? Do you have control of the data or is it provided to you by a third party?

Comment: no, the values from each columns are not enclosed by anything @MikeWalton

Comment: Sorry, just realized you were extracting the data.  You should be able to use just the FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY parameter to quote-qualify your data on the way out.  Your other option would be to use a different delimiter that isn't used in your data at all.

Comment: im confused because in the document under ESCAPE, it says "You can use the ESCAPE character to interpret instances of the FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY character in the data as literals."  not sure why we need to use them together.... https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#optional-parameters    @MikeWalton

Comment: if you use a double-quote as your FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY, then you'd need to ESCAPE any double-quotes that are in your values so that whatever is ingesting your data would know which of the quotes is terminating your data vs. is your data.